# get() method in Key in Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Now I am confused with `get` methods in `Key` class.
My question is just about which a `get` method is used in the below code.
But, I can't find the appropriate method.  Of course,I have already checked the API reference, but I couldn't find the likely method.
See this code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(
        new DatabaseModule(),
        new WebserverModule(),
        ...
    );

    Service databaseConnectionPool = injector.getInstance(
        Key.get(Service.class, DatabaseService.class));
    databaseConnectionPool.start();
    addShutdownHook(databaseConnectionPool);

    Service webserver = injector.getInstance(
        Key.get(Service.class, WebserverService.class));
    webserver.start();
    addShutdownHook(webserver);
  }
```

The second argument seems to be `T extends V` where the first argument is `V`.   Although this is just my assumption, so which method in `Key` class is used in this code?

Comment: What prevents you from opening the code in any modern IDE and using "navigate to method"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All overloads of `Key.get` feature a *type* as the first argument and an *annotation class or instance* as the optional second argument. [See the docs.](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/Key.html)

```
Key.get(Class<T> type)
Key.get(Class<T> type, Annotation annotation)
Key.get(Class<T> type, Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType)  // THIS ONE
Key.get(Type type)
Key.get(Type type, Annotation annotation))
Key.get(Type type, Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType))
Key.get(TypeLiteral<T> typeLiteral)
Key.get(TypeLiteral<T> typeLiteral, Annotation annotation))
Key.get(TypeLiteral<T> typeLiteral, Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType))
```

Because your calls feature a second argument that is a class, they must be the third overload above (marked "THIS ONE") that take two classes: One of the type, and one of the annotation class.

```
// Matches injections of "@DatabaseService Service"
Key.get(Service.class, DatabaseService.class)

// Matches injections of "@WebserverService Service"
Key.get(Service.class, WebserverService.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no relationship between first and second parameters, second parameter can be any annotation. 
You should bind Service class to different implementations through different annotations(DatabaseService and WebserverService in this case).